# Get status code for request sent using pysimplesoap

Tags: python, pysimplesoap

I'm using [Pysimplesoap](http://code.google.com/p/pysimplesoap/) for sending a data to the web-service. I want to know the status of the request code. I'm able to print a traceback using `trace=True`. Over there it does prints the status code and other response variables but how do I get the to store all the traceback into a variable and then check the status code for the same?

Here's my code :_

```
client = SoapClient(
                    location = url,
                    action = 'http://tempuri.org/IService_1_0/',
                    namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", 
                    soap_ns='soap', ns = False,trace = True
                    )

data = {'AWB_Number' : '406438762211111', 'Weight':'0.023' ,'Length':'16.4','Height':'4.5','Width':'9.9'}
response= client.UpdateShipment(
                                ShipmentNumber = data['AWB_Number'], 
                                Weight = Decimal(data['Weight']), 
                                Length = Decimal(data['Length']), 
                                Height = Decimal(data['Height']), 
                                Width =  Decimal(data['Width']) , 
                                InboundLane = "2",
                                SequenceNumber = "1", 
                                )
```

I do get a traceback :-

```
Content-length: 526
Content-type: text/xml; charset="UTF-8"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
    <UpdateShipment xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber><Weight>0.023</Weight><Height>4.5</Height><Width>9.9</Width><Length>16.4</Length><ShipmentNumber>406438762211111</ShipmentNumber><InboundLane>2</InboundLane></UpdateShipment>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
status: 200
content-length: 293
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
date: Sat, 23 Aug 2014 07:27:38 GMT
content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><UpdateShipmentResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><UpdateShipmentResult/></UpdateShipmentResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
===============================================================================
```

There's a status code mention there as `200`, but I dont get to store this traceback into a variable to get to know the status code of it. A human need to intervene to have a look at the status code. How do my program gets to know the status code?

Comment: How do you get a traceback, is it just printed there? what is the output of `dir(response)`?

Comment: By enabling a parameter, `trace` to True

Comment: Yes, it just printed over there. Thats it. Used for debugging.

Comment: what does `output of dir(response)`?

Comment: prints `[u's:Body']`

Comment: Setting `trace=True` sets up [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html); you'd have to capture that by configuring logging to not go to stderr. I looked for a better option, but the library does not preserve the status code in any accessible manner; the `urllib2` response object that holds the status code is discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SoapClient` instance retains a `.response` attribute, containing information about the response. What that information is depends on the transport picked.

If you have *just* PySimpleSoap installed, the `urllib2` library is picked and the status code is not part of the `client.response` attribute; the information is not retained from the actual response from `urllib2`, only the HTTP headers are preserved.

The `pycurl` transport gives you even less info; `client.response` is always an empty dictionary then.

Only if you also installed `httplib2` will you get anything useful out of this; `client.response` is then set to a dictionary that includes a `status` code:

```
>>> import pysimplesoap
>>> client = pysimplesoap.client.SoapClient(wsdl='http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL')
>>> response = client.GetQuote('GOOG')
>>> client.response
{'status': '200', 'content-length': '991', 'x-aspnet-version': '4.0.30319', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server': 'Microsoft-IIS/7.0', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 'date': 'Sat, 23 Aug 2014 08:05:19 GMT', 'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET', 'content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'}
>>> client.response['status']
'200'
```

Note that the value is a string, not an integer.

The `httplib2` transport is picked by default if available.

As for the `trace` option; that sets up a [`logging` module log](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html), calls `logging.basicConfig()` with a log level and gets on with it. You could add a custom handler to the `pysimplesoap.client.log` object, but I wouldn't bother, really. If you see the status logged to the trace, then in all likelihood you are *already* using `httplib2` and can access the status code more directly. For `urllib2`, for example, no status is logged either. That's because it is the `client.response.items()` values that are being logged here.

Comment: Can you please provide your thoughts on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483984/python-retry-a-failed-celery-task-from-another-queue Thanks

Comment: @user1162512: please don't ping me for completely unrelated questions. I see loads of questions each day, if I can answer I will.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didnt intend to disturb you. I just thought you could help. Thanks anyways. :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [pysimplesoap](http://code.google.com/p/pysimplesoap) source code, at line 261 of client, the [`send` method](http://code.google.com/p/pysimplesoap/source/browse/pysimplesoap/client.py#261) is written which is used to send the http request from client's end

Taking cue from it,

```
def send(self, method, xml):
    ...    
    response, content = self.http.request(
        location, 'POST', body=xml, headers=headers)
    self.response = response
    self.content = content
    ...
```

you should be able to access `client.response` to get the raw response for the request. From there, try doing a `client.response.status`, or do a [`dir(client.response)`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#dir) to find out any supportive method to get status code.

**EDIT**

As mentioned [here](http://code.google.com/p/pysimplesoap/source/browse/pysimplesoap/transport.py#273) in `transport` module, you can specifiy a  library (`like urllib2` or `httplib2`). to make it the default one to be picked up.

Comment: That depends on the transport picked, and for the ones I could test the `response` attribute does not contain the status.

Comment: For the CURL transport, that value is an empty dictionary, for the `urllib2` transport, that value is the result of `response.info()`, which doesn't contain the status (`response.getcode()` would be used instead).

Comment: @MartijnPieters  What if we change the library at [runtime](http://code.google.com/p/pysimplesoap/source/browse/pysimplesoap/transport.py#273)? That would ensure that a particular method only runs

Comment: You could provide your own transport I suppose, but with `httplib2` installed things work.