# How do I move tasks from one queue to another in celery

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq, celery

I need to be able to do two things, both of which depend on my being able to move tasks from one queue to another.:

1. when task fails certain number of retries, move it to another queue
2. when task meets certain conditions, move it to different queue (where it will be processed by a different worker)

Do note that I mean to put stuff in another queue from one task in a worker - not from the main app.

The only piece of code that I can find to do this is referenced here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27144119/112050
can someone point out the correct api to do this ?

Comment: For the case "2." above, when/how do you intend to detect that the "task meets certain conditions"? Is it from inside the running task? Is it from another task before the task in question is running? Can you clarify or give an example of what you want in your case "2."?

Answer (score 3):

Your idea of *moving* a task actually comes down to running the same task with the same parameters but sending it to a different queue.

[apply_async](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.delay) has a `queue` parameter

```
from celery.exceptions import MaxRetriesExceededError

@shared_task(default_retry_delay = 1 * 60, max_retries = 10)
def some_task(arg1, arg2):
    try:
        # task logic

        if some_condition:
            some_task.apply_async([arg1, arg2], queue='different_queue')
            return

    except MaxRetriesExceededError:
        some_task.apply_async([arg1, arg2], queue='different_queue')

    except Exception, exc:
        raise some_task.retry(exc=exc)
```

If you actually want to move tasks between queues, assuming you are using RabbitMQ, you can use the [Shovel Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html). For example to move messages from queue `q1` to queue `q2` on the local broker:

```
rabbitmqctl set_parameter shovel my-shovel \
'{"src-uri": "amqp://", "src-queue": "q1", \
 "dest-uri": "amqp://", "dest-queue": "q2"}'
```